# Splitting Android SendSMS

Tags: android, sms

My first problem is that any string longer that 1 word screws with the contact. For example: if I send "yo man", instead of coming up "5554: yo man" on the other emulator, it comes up as "yo: man". Second is the "sendMultipartTextMessage" I call when to string is too long (over 150 chars). It sends the proper amount of messages, but the messages themselves are just sequences of weird characters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are either of these things happening?

Answer (score 0):

Using SmsManager is pretty straight foward:

```
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, MessageText, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

On the receiving end it should not show anything unnatural using this method.

I recommend you search for it, as well as the splitting.  A more specific question would provide a better answer, but a a good resource for SMS anything/everything resides at the [SmsPopup Source](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/source/browse/trunk/SMSPopup/src/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/SmsMessageSender.java#215)

Comment: That's exactly how I have it set up, which is why I don't see why I'm having these issues. In fact, the message splitting works--when I run a debug I see that the string array is all correct. It's probably the emulator, I'll try to run it on real devices and see what's up.